# Elastic search more like this Query score issue in 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nest

Recently we have changed **Elasticsearch** version from **2.4 to 5.4** .

we found one issue in more like this query in version 5.x .

following query is used  to find out similar documents by text

> **INPUT Query**

```
POST /test/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
"stored_fields": [
"docid"
],
 "_source": false,
"query": {
"more_like_this": {
"fields": [
    "textcontent"
  ],
  "like": [
    {
      "_index": "test",
      "_type": "object",
      "_id": "AV0c9jvZXF-b5U5aNAWB"
    }
  ],
  "max_query_terms": 5000,
  "min_term_freq": 1,
  "min_doc_freq": 1
}
}
}
```

> **Output of Elasticsearch 2.4**

```
{

"took": 16,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.5381224,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal6Z9",
            "_score": 1.5381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        },  {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal63Z",
            "_score": .5381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        },  {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal6Z",
            "_score": .381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "4"
                ]
            }
        }
```

> **Output of Elasticsearch 5.4**
>       {

```
"took": 16,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.5381224,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal6Z9",
            "_score": 168.5381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        },  {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal63Z",
            "_score": 164.5381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "3"
                ]
            }
        },  {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "object",
            "_id": "AVzjOOdilllQ-Gyal6Z",
            "_score": 132.381224,
            "fields": {
                "docid": [
                    "4"
                ]
            }
        }}
```

The output is same in both versions  **except the score** of the documents.
version 5.4 is giving more score than 2.4. 
We are dependent on score for our work so if the score changes then its a problem for us. Please provide solution for this?

Comment: Can you use the `explain` option with your query to see what provides the differences in scores?

Comment: Thanks   I got solution it was internal algorithm bm25 .
Need to change it classic.

Comment: Sure no problem, when you can, can you write an answer to your question to help keep the focus on unanswered questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution,In version 5.0  they have changed default similarity algorithm from classic to BM25 that was the reason for it.
Just change similarity type to classic while creating index.
and 
if index is already exist then just update setting for all indices  by executing following query

```
PUT /_all/_settings?preserve_existing=true          
{
  "index.similarity.default.type": "classic"
}
```